# Can't remove a child fragment in another one

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment in another one and I add and commit it succussfuly, but when I want to remove it, it doesn't work and always is where it was.

## Main Activity Fragment

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    ScreenUtility screenUtility;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        screenUtility = new ScreenUtility(getActivity());

        TotalAmountFragment totalAmountFragment;
        totalAmountFragment = new TotalAmountFragment();

        if (screenUtility.getOrientation() == 1){
            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.main_total_amount_fragment_container, totalAmountFragment, "totalPrice")
                    .commit();
        } else if (screenUtility.getOrientation() == 2 && getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("totalPrice") != null){
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.remove(totalAmountFragment);
            transaction.commit();
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

## XML File

```
 ...
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_total_amount_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

What should I do? I did whatever I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
```

Comment: Not working! When the tablet is landscape at first start the fragment isn't added, and when I rotate it to portrait the child fragment appears correctly, but when I rotate the device again to landscape it won't remove!

Comment: Why don't you straightaway replace the fragment?

Comment: Replace with what?

Comment: On orientation change instead on removing the fragment replace it with the previous fragment

Comment: It has not a previous fragment, it is new in another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (screenUtility.getOrientation() == 1){
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_total_amount_fragment_container, totalAmountFragment, "totalPrice")
                .commit();
    } else {
        Fragment priceFragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("totalPrice");
        if (priceFragment != null){
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(priceFragment).commit();
        }
    }
```